# Difference between History Operator and Occurrence in PineScript

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Is there any difference when using the History Operator or Occurrence in the following line of code? or do both lines of code give the same end result?

`

```
ta.valuewhen(ta.crossover(ema1 , ema2)[1], close, 0)
ta.valuewhen(ta.crossover(ema1 , ema2)[0], close, 1)
```

`

I tried both options and I believe it does the same thing but my knowledge is limited so would like confirmation, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not the same but that is also comparing apples and oranges in my opinion.

You should break it down a little to understand how they work.

Let's look at the following example:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

ema1 = ta.ema(close, 10)
ema2 = ta.ema(close, 20)

co = ta.crossover(ema1 , ema2)
co_prev = co[1]

val1 = ta.valuewhen(co_prev, close, 0)
val2 = ta.valuewhen(co, close, 1)

plot(ema1, color=color.green)
plot(ema2, color=color.red)

plotshape(co, color=color.green)
plotshape(co_prev, color=color.red, location=location.belowbar)

plot(val1, color=color.yellow)
plot(val2, color=color.orange)
```

`co_prev`  will follow `co` on the next bar.

Whenever `co_prev` is `true`, `val1` will get the `close` price of that bar.

Whenever `co` is `true`, `val2` will get the `close` price of the previous occurence (bar) where `co` was `true`.

Run the above code and follow `val1` and `val2` plots.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed response. It took me a while to wrap my head around all this.

As I understand it, it isn't possible to use the history-referencing operator to find the last occurrences of a condition. Is that accurate? 

You're also saying co[1] is the index of the bar/close value right before the crossover condition was met. I tried to make a visual sketch below as I understand it:

. . . . . . [3] [2] [1] [0]
. . . co[2] co[1] co . . .

Comment: My confusion stemmed from the barssince function which seemed to refer to the previous occurrence when using [1] but I now understand this was also incorrect.

I am using a custom function to use the barssince function to find the previous occurrence of a condition:

f_barssince(_cond, _count) => _barssince = bar_index - ta.valuewhen(_cond, bar_index, _count)

Thank you kind sir!